# remove empty json array from array object while doing map in mule 3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

How can i apply the filter to remove empty array while doing transformation. I tried to apply sizeOf ($) != 0 but that is not working. I am able to do this by creating function but here i have to remove while doing map.kindly suggest solution for that.

```
            %dw 1.0
            %output application/json
            ---
            {
            employees: {
                employee:  (flowVars.varInputData.request.application.applicants) map ((applicant , indexOfApplicant) -> {
                        (flowVars.varMbResponse.application.applicants filter ($.customerID == applicant.customerID) map {
                        "source": "EMI_IMP",
                        "loanData": ($.customBureauResponse.customResponse.accountList map {
                                    "customerGender": applicant.gender
                })
                })

                })  
            }
            }
```

Response from the dwl:

```
            {
            "EMIComputations": {
                "eMIComputation": [{
                        "source": "EMI_IMP",
                        "loanData": [{
                                "customerGender": "F",
                            },
                            {
                                "customerGender": "M",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
            }
```

expected output:

```
            "EMIComputations": {
                "eMIComputation": [{
                        "source": "EMI_IMP",
                        "loanData": [{
                                "customerGender": "M",
                            },
                            {
                                "customerGender": "M",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
            }
```

Comment: Try changing your expression to `(sizeOf $) != 0` and try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove empty array objects from dataweave response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043075/how-to-remove-empty-array-objects-from-dataweave-response)

Comment: @aled by using function i am also able to do but i have to remove in one transformation when i am doing map

Comment: Just apply the function where you needed. For example to map the payload without the empty values: `(filterEmpty(payload)) map ...`. There is not way to automate it, if that is what you are asking for.